# Update image without changing size

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

the point is that I have to repeat the same swf with different texts and images.

The problem comes **when I update the image symbol since the image size is messed up despite having same resolution and aspect ratio**.

My question is this, **Is there anyway to make Adobe Flash Professional keep the size of the symbol alone while changing the image file ?**

UPDATE:

How do I use

```
var originalWidth:int = button4.width / button4.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = button4.height / button4.scaleY;
```

several times with different images ?

Answer (score 0):

This would not work if **scaleX** or **scaleY** are zero or nearly so, but otherwise you can get the original width and height as following:

```
var originalWidth:int = image.width / image.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = image.height / image.scaleY;
```